# Creating common views in android xml

Tags: android, xml

I have a linear layout with a `weightSum=3` and `orientation=horizontal`. Within the linear layout, I have 3 child linear layouts, each has a `layout_weight=1`, icon and a textview as shown below:

The problem I am facing is I don't want to have to edit each of the linear layouts in multiple places, is there a way to encapsulate this? where I can just set the icon and the text view and the encapsulated the padding, scaletype of the image

[image]

Here is my xml, I'm showing the first two for brevity:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/paddingLarge"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/paddingLarge"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/paddingLarge">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/paddingSmall">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/bottomsheet_option_icon"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/bottomsheet_option_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/priority_icon" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Priority"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/paddingSmall"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/bottomsheet_option_icon"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/bottomsheet_option_icon"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/date_time_icon"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Priority"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/bottomsheet_option_icon"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/bottomsheet_option_icon"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/notification_icon"/>

            <TextView
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Priority"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use this:     *<include layout="you_layout"/>*

Comment: but how would I change my icon for the individual layout?

Comment: set in your code, not xml

Answer (score 0):

Create a "CustomView".
Include the inflation in the "CustomLinearLayout" structure that inherited the "LinearLayout".
Then create a controller for "ImageView" and "TextView".

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/paddingSmall">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/bottomsheet_option_icon"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottomsheet_option_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/priority_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Priority"/>
</LinearLayout>
```